# Problem with VPN and MTU size in UBUNTU 18.10

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I am currently using UBUNTU 18.10 and before this I was using 18.04 , but in the both of them when I want to use VPN (ANY VPN ) I have to change the mtu size to 1270 `sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 mtu 1270` and if I don't do this most websites don't work correctly(pictures won't be shown or some of them don't open at all)

Last week I changed my OS to UBUNTU 19.04 and the problem solved but for some reasons I had to come back to 18.10 version

By the way , I thought the problem was my VPN service provider but I've changed it and still have this problem and in the windows or Android I don't have to change anything

Is this a bug or something in UBUNTU ?

**UPDATE 1**

```
Without VPN
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.1.1                                           1.573ms 
 1:  192.168.1.1                                           1.473ms 
 2:  no reply
 3:  10.177.107.129                                       70.725ms 
 4:  10.177.99.88                                         29.873ms 
 5:  no reply
 6:  10.177.99.97                                         91.461ms 
 7:  no reply
 8:  10.137.99.30                                         61.386ms 
 9:  10.137.108.6                                         44.915ms 
10:  10.21.249.238                                        90.055ms 
11:  10.21.71.20                                          82.133ms asymm 12 
12:  10.21.71.20                                          77.988ms 
13:  193.251.150.199                                     268.404ms 
14:  193.251.154.103                                     204.592ms asymm 13 
15:  193.251.243.249                                     172.388ms asymm 14 
16:  193.251.249.202                                     237.009ms asymm 20 
17:  193.251.249.202                                     205.426ms asymm 20 
18:  64.125.29.16                                        203.375ms asymm 20 
19:  64.125.29.16                                        158.389ms asymm 20 
20:  64.125.29.81                                        251.842ms asymm 19 
21:  64.125.31.217                                       155.117ms asymm 16 
22:  64.125.29.58                                        254.295ms asymm 18 
23:  64.125.31.217                                       185.134ms asymm 16 
24:  no reply
25:  no reply
26:  no reply
27:  no reply
28:  no reply
29:  no reply
30:  no reply
     Too many hops: pmtu 1500
     Resume: pmtu 1500 



with VPN
1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1400
 1:  no reply
 2:  54.38.75.25                                         193.406ms 
 3:  145.239.5.252                                       173.050ms 
 4:  10.50.112.124                                       237.138ms 
 5:  10.72.1.10                                          204.673ms 
 6:  10.73.32.8                                          156.910ms 
 7:  10.73.249.2                                         252.333ms 
 8:  213.186.32.252                                      148.465ms 
 9:  94.23.122.144                                       173.819ms 
10:  94.23.122.243                                       155.159ms 
11:  no reply
12:  130.117.3.101                                       147.622ms 
13:  130.117.14.142                                      160.425ms 
14:  195.219.194.5                                       153.079ms 
15:  no reply
16:  no reply
17:  no reply
18:  no reply
19:  no reply
20:  no reply
21:  no reply
22:  no reply
23:  no reply
24:  no reply
25:  no reply
26:  no reply
27:  no reply
28:  no reply
29:  no reply
30:  no reply
     Too many hops: pmtu 1400
     Resume: pmtu 1400
```

Tracepath output : https://gofile.io/?c=pp7Lfx

Comment: It would be instructive to run `tracepath www.ebay.com` with and without VPN. Install `iputils-tracepath` if you don't have it. Are you running a cable or DSL modem? Edit that output into your question and I'll take a look.

Comment: @heynnema with the default mtu size in both(1500) ?

Comment: Yes, try 1500 first. Are you running cable or DSL modem?

Comment: I'm using LTE modem (Wireless)

Comment: @heynnema I update the post with tracepath output

Comment: You're running 18.10 now, yes? I thought that we were going to run both tests with MTU=1500, but the VPN test is 1400? In either case, I don't see the MTU value changing through the path. For wireless, MTU 1270 sounds about right. 19.04 probably auto-fixed the MTU problem... you'd have to look at the 19.04 release notes to confirm. Do you want me to answer with a MTU test program?

Comment: I added file.txt directly into your question.

Comment: just for curiosity: have you run speedtests? does an mtu of 1500 to 1270 do include any bandwith changes?

Comment: @AlexOnLinux it should be faster with the correct MTU.

Comment: i know that it should. but often theory and praxis are not equal.

Comment: the MTU size for 1270 and 1500 are almost the same but with 1270 I have a bit lower speed (speedtest.net)@AlexOnLinux @heynnema

Answer (score 3):

To properly determine the correct MTU setting for your LTE modem (Wireless)...

There's a MTU setting in Ubuntu's network configuration, and a WAN MTU setting in your router.

<strike>For DSL, a common MTU setting is 1492. Just go ahead and try this value first and see if your web sites are now accessible.</strike>

To determine the correct setting, start with all MTU settings = 1500 and VPN = off. (VPN requires different testing).

In terminal:

```
ping [-c count] [-M do] [-s packet_size] [host]
```

The options used are:

- `c count`: number of times to ping
- `M hint`: Select Path MTU Discovery strategy.  may be either `do` (prohibit fragmentation, even local one), `want` (do PMTU discovery, fragment locally when packet size is large), or `dont` (do not set DF flag).
- `s packet_size`: Specifies the number of data bytes to be sent.

You should always start at 1472 and work your way down by 10 each time. Once you get a reply, go up by 1 until you get a fragmented packet. Take that value (last good value) and add 28 to the value to account for the various TCP/IP headers. Eg. let's say that 1452 was the proper packet size (where you first got an ICMP reply to your ping). The actual MTU size would be 1480, which is the optimum for the network we're working with.

```
ping -c 4 -M do -s 1472 8.8.8.8 # this will probably show fragmentation

ping -c 4 -M do -s 1462 8.8.8.8 # may show fragmentation

ping -c 4 -M do -s 1452 8.8.8.8 # no fragmentation?

ping -c 4 -M do -s 1453 8.8.8.8 # still no fragmentation?
```

reference: [How to determine the proper MTU size with ICMP pings](http://muzso.hu/2009/05/17/how-to-determine-the-proper-mtu-size-with-icmp-pings)

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but I used it before and the the only MTU size that worked for me , it was 1270